What is the right way to compare snapshots with the render method?
My snapshots logs are empty when rendering without an assignment to a var and using the screen from 'react-testing-library':
render(<Element/>); 
expect(screen).toMatchSnapshot();

Do I really need to use jsx.debug as the example below (also known as screen.debug method) to check snapshots by assigning it to a variable and comparing it afterwards? This code below outputs a non-empty (valid) snapshot.
describe('Table', () => {
  let jsx;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jsx = render(<Table {...baseProps} />);
    jsx.debug();
  });

  it('match snapshot', () => {
    expect(jsx).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('renders children correctly', () => {
    checkBasicStructure(jsx.debug()); 
  });
});

